# how change laragon Hostname domain?

Tags: php, apache, laragon

I am using laragon as virtual host.
As per the latest chrome update which made any local site end with .dev extension force it to redirect to https so they give error and can't view them in chrome, How I can change the .dev extension with .test to be able to continue developing usin chrome?
How can i change virtual hostname from {name}.dev to {name}.test ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click **Menu > Preferences**, change the hostname format to: 

`{name}.test`

Comment: it's not the correct solution, when we just change the virtual host from menu>preferences , it will produce an error